# Go type cast fails despite the type being the same

Tags: go, casting, go-gorm

I am using the [jackc/pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/tree/v5.3.0) driver alongside the GORM library to interface with a PostgreSQL database.

I have an instance where I have to check the PostgreSQL error code and handle a certain error type differently. When using the `pgx` driver, the GORM methods return a `*pgconn.PgError` type as the `error`, which contains a field with the specific error code.

In order to access that field, I must cast the `error` to a `*pgconn.PgError`, but for some reason this is failing:

```golang
res := tx.Take(&f, "id = ?", id)
if res.Error != nil {
    if pqErr, ok := res.Error.(*pgconn.PgError); ok {
        // does not reach here
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Error type: %T\n", res.Error)
        // Output: "Error type: *pgconn.PgError"
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. The `pgx` and `pgconn` packages are inside the **same project**, so it's not the case that they are returning different versions of a type with the same name. In other words, I only have one import in my go.mod.
2. The returned value is not nil.
3. A debugger reveals that the type is a `*pgconn.PgError`.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to inspect the values at runtime?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Yes, the debugger also says that the type is `*pgconn.PgError`

Comment: Have you tried using reflect to verify the full path of the type, i.e., `reflect.TypeOf(res.Error).PkgPath()`?

Comment: [`github.com/jackc/pgconn`](https://github.com/jackc/pgconn) and [`github.com/jackc/pgx/pgconn`](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/tree/master/pgconn) may be coexisting in your program. In general, packages of the same name can exist in the same program as long as they have different import paths.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco ah that was it, thanks! Not sure how I would have arrived at this solution though, as the reflect `PkgPath()` returns an empty string, and the `go.mod` of `pgx` does not show that it imports `github.com/jackc/pgconn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've solved your own issue, but here's some perhaps helpful background, and how I found the source.

Packages of the same name can exist in the same program, so long as they have different import paths. For example, the standard library has both `math/rand` and `crypto/rand`, each called `rand`. This is the first hint of how `*pgconn.PgError` and `*pgconn.PgError` are not the same: they come from different import paths.

When modules in Go make [major revisions](https://go.dev/doc/modules/major-version), they are supposed to change their import path. This is to preserve backwards compatibility with respect to import paths. Note that this is usually done by updating the `module` declaration in the `go.mod` file, rather than actually moving the code into a sub-directory. For example, see this [commit](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/commit/72cc95e4dd18576691da38c46c7e6a101869c10a#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5R28) where `pgx` was bumped from `v4` to `v5`. This is the second hint: code from the `pgx` project is available under multiple import paths (due to the multiple major versions).

With this background in mind, I used the git tags to view the repository at the latest `v4.x.x` [release](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/tree/v4.18.0). I noticed that oddly, the `pgconn` package did not exist in `v4`. This seemed to rule out the idea of a `github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgconn` vs `github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgconn` conflict. I then Google searched for "pgconn" and found the `github.com/jackc/pgconn` repository, where I saw in the README:

> This version is used with pgx v4. In pgx v5 it is part of the https://github.com/jackc/pgx repository.

From the other information you've given, your mistake may have been using the import path `"github.com/jackc/pgx/pgconn"`. As shown in the example code for `pgx`, the current import path you should be using for the base module is `"github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"`, and packages within it would be specified similarly, e.g., `"github.com/jackc/pgx/v5/pgconn"`.

Answer (score 1):

As @HymnsForDisco correctly pointed out in the comments, both `github.com/jackc/pgconn` and `github.com/jackc/pgx/pgconn` exist. It turns out that the returned error was from the former, whereas I was importing the latter in my code.

To confirm, I added the following line:

```golang
fmt.Println("Error path: ", reflect.TypeOf(res.Error).Elem().PkgPath())
// Output: "Error path:  github.com/jackc/pgconn"
```

Changing my import to "github.com/jackc/pgconn" resolved the issue.